Horror movie about husband and wife authors in Mom's death apartment
I watched this movie years ago, maybe 10 years ago. It is a horror movie about a (probably newlywed) husband and wife who were authors. They move to the hotel or apartment where the wife's mother died (when she was a child) to write a book on her I believe. The dead mother keeps calling the daughter and doing a bunch of creepy stuff.
Eventually the husband leaves the wife (for being crazy I think). The most horrifying scene was when the wife took a shower and turns around and there is her dead mother, so she runs out of the apartment or hotel into the housekeeper who checks the apartment and says nobody is in there.
The ending is the wife signing books and making it big while the husband walks by and isn't making it big. BTW, This is not Psycho.

Was this movie old or recent when you saw it 10 years ago?

The independent horror film The Off Season from 2004 seems like a match. It's about a couple who move to a motel so the guy can write in quiet, then discover that it's haunted. The woman is a librarian, and gets so sick from this that the guy leaves her. But according to IMDb:

Our heroine triumphs in the end writing her own best seller

Here's the trailer, where you can also see the woman's dead mother calling them on the phone (0:33) and a creepy ghost startling the woman in the shower (0:56).
